# How to remember which URL the user was accessing before registration

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am developing a Laravel application and I need some suggestion.

I have a page which when a user who is not logged in access, it redirects to the login page and after authentication, he is back to the same. This works fine.

The problem is that if the user was a new user. He doesnot have a login and goes for Registration.

He then registers and the application redirects him to several other pages (like e.g.He needs to verify his email) and when all is done he will be on the dashboard page.

Now is there any way, I can save that he was on certain page and after registering and moving through all those pages come back to the same page?

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: Did any of the answers resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't posted any code I'd write a general explanation of how I think you should handle this.

In short - you can get the indented url and add it to the registration button as a query parameter i.e `yourdomain.com/register?origin=some_route`.

So assuming you have a register button/link on your login page, add the origin to the link href:

`<a href="register?origin=some_route">Register<a>`

This way, when you finish the registration, you can simply access the `origin` by using `\Input::get('origin')`.

Now, to actually get the intended url you can either try and get it from the Session by using:
`\Session::get('url.intended', url('/'))`

or you could use `\Redirect::intended(url('/'))->getTargetUrl();`

In both cases `url('/')` is used as a fallback url to the homepage and you could replace it with any other url you wish.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could do something like this for one page:

```
return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
```

which would the the same as

```
 return \Redirect::intended('/dashboard');
```

As per docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users

> The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being caught by the authentication filter. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

Alternately, if you're going through a multi-page login 'wizard' type deal, I'd personally store the initial value of redirect()->intended in a Session or Cookie, and redirect to the value of the session / cookie once your registration process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of intended redirect function you can print the HTTP referer in a hidden field in the form, then after login redirect to that URL.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{URL::previous()}}">
```

Controller:

```
if(Input::get('redirect') && (Input::get('redirect') != url('/path/to/login/'))){
    return redirect(Input::get('redirect'));
}
else{
    return redirect('/alternative/page');
}
```